# How to make radio transmitter and reciver

Tags: radio

I want to make a simple but useful radio transmitter and reciver.I dont know which one is better, Fm or Am or other types?

Just want it to send pulses like morse code not complicated voice or other stuffs.(plus all things needed like transistors and capacitors)

If possible i want to configure its frequancey myself,
Even if you could give me a good webpage, it would be great!

Thanks alot.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question/

Comment: @Qmechanic is it possible to transfer this post into Electrical engineering or i should make another post there?

Answer (score 2):

You can find many different radio designs online, from those built as projects in introductory electrical engineering courses to home-built HAM systems.

Many of these require power supplies, oscilloscopes and other equipment; so I located a truly simple AM radio system for you to look at [here, the foxhole radio!](http://bizarrelabs.com/foxhole.htm)

Comment: PS: you may do better on the electrical engineering forum.